# 8 Queens chess problem with various chess pieces

Tags: c++

I'm trying to solve the 8 Queens on an 8x8 chess board problem with various chess pieces like a rook or a knight. I'm trying to use classes and virtualization and inheritance because the combination of a rook and a bishop make a queen.

the main class is a piece which follows this format:

```
class Piece {
protected:
    int _row, _column;

public:
    int row() const {
    return _row;
    }

    int column() const {
    return _column;
    }

    void place(int row, int column) {
    _row = row;
    _column = column;
    }

    virtual bool menaces(const Piece *p) const = 0;
};
```

the rook class overwrites the menaces class which is used to check if 2 pieces can attack each other:

```
class Rook: virtual public Piece {
 public:
  virtual bool menaces(Piece *p){
    if(this->row()==p->row()){
      return(true);
    }
    if(this->column()==p->column()){
      return(true);
    }
    return(false);
  }
};
```

The Queens piece will later inherit from the Rook and Bishop. The issue comes in when I try to create a new Rook object, I get the error:

```
cannot allocate an object of abstract type 'Rook'
```

I'm not sure how to correctly allocate a virtual class and any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Any class that derives from `Piece` must provide an implementation for the method `bool menaces(const Piece*) const`.

In the `Rook` class, you provide a method `bool menaces(Piece*)` which does not override the function in `Piece` because the signature is different! So the class is still abstract because the definition of that base method is still missing. Change the definition of `menacing` in `Rook` to match that in `Piece`.

You should mark the function in the `Rook` class as `override` instead of `virtual`, that way the compiler will actually generate a warning about this.